# Nested React component not updating 'grandchilds'

Tags: reactjs

I have 3 nested selects: Country -> State -> City.

But when I change the Country, the State is updated but not the City.

The code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/change-a-selects-options-based-on-another-dropdown-using-react-forked-hjfr2m?file=/src/App.js

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Please provide a minimal reproducible example and not just a link to a CodeSandbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a useEffect in your `Category` component :

```
useEffect(()=> {
  if (category) setSelected(category.options[0])
}, [category])
```

Answer (score 0):

That is correct. When you change country, onChange in State

```
<select onChange={handleChange}>{options}</select>
```

gets triggered. So it changes the value. Since you are not triggering State, City is untouched